# Must we manually log errors in Firebase Cloud Functions or will they log automatically?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have this cloud function currently deployed. It returns a promise as required by Firebase to terminate the function.

```
exports.userDidSignOut = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
    const userId = data.userId;
    const settingsUpdate = {
        "fcmToken": null,
    };
    const promise = admin.firestore().collection("user-settings").doc(userId).update(settingsUpdate);

    return promise
});
```

However, will this log errors on the console automatically? Or must I log them manually (as below)?

```
exports.userDidSignOut = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
    const userId = data.userId;
    const settingsUpdate = {
        "fcmToken": null,
    };
    const promise = admin.firestore().collection("user-settings").doc(userId).update(settingsUpdate);

    promise.then(() => {
        return null;
    }, (reason) => {
        console.log(reason);
        return null;
    });
});
```

And is it necessary to return `null` in the failure function to terminate the cloud function or is printing to the console sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an entire documentation page on [handling errors in Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/reporting-errors). From there:

> Uncaught exceptions produced by your function will appear in [Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs).

So you don't have to do this yourself, although you *can* of course always do so to add additional context around the error.